# Turtlebot Simulator in ROS Hydro

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can anyone tell me whether the turtlebot gazebo simulator will be available in the Hydromedusa beta?

Thanks,

Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68122/turtlebot-simulator-in-ros-hydro/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the simulator is there, but it is work in progress. We are working on getting it back in shape for the full release of Hydro.

If you don't want to wait until then, you can try out the shadow-fixed debian packages or a source install.

**However, since it's work in progress expect only partially implemented features and even broken versions!**

We will announce the simulator on ros-users, once it is ready.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2